# HTML/JS random audio script has stopped functioning

Tags: javascript, html

a script I used for the longest time now will not work unless I remove some of the audio links from the list of audio files to be played on the website. I absolutely don't know what's causing this.

### The script in question:

```
<script>

var collection=[];
var loadedIndex=0;


function init(audios) {
  for(var i=0;i<audios.length;i++) {
    var audio = new Audio(audios[i]);
    collection.push(audio);
    buffer(audio);
  }
}

function buffer(audio) {
  if(audio.readyState==4)return loaded();
  setTimeout(function(){buffer(audio)},100);
}

function loaded() {
  loadedIndex++;
  if(collection.length==loadedIndex)playLooped();
}

function playLooped() {
var audio=Math.floor(Math.random() * (collection.length));
  audio=collection[audio];
  audio.play();
  setTimeout(playLooped,audio.duration*1000);
}



init([

// (Every single audio file link that I have inserted)

]);

</script>
```

### from: https://stackoverflow.com/users/688411/khez

### [Playing random audio in HTML/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247998/playing-random-audio-in-html-javascript)

The script's main purpose is to pick a random piece of audio to play when the website loads, and when the chosen audio file stops playing it picks another random track to play, and so on and so forth.

It all worked well so I kept adding more and more tracks until it suddenly stopped working. The only way I fixed it was by removing some from the list, except I didn't want to remove any because the tracks were amazing / a perfect fit for the site.

Searching for a solution didn't help either. So now im looking for a way to play the abundance of tracks I have inserted into this script without it breaking.

### (Edit)

### The links I use are from:

downloads.khinsider.com (VideoGameMusic)

archive.org (I host 199X / 200X video game music if I can't find any on VGM site)

### And the links look like so:

archive.org links:
https://ia601403.us.archive.org/20/items/passport1_202210/passport1.mp3

VGM links:
https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/3d-minigolf-deluxe/wgbpcldrlj/Theme1.mp3

### In total there are 70 lines of tracks in the list

Now, that is not to say that the links I use are *broken or removed,* no. They work perfectly well and none have been removed / will not be removed in the future. I have tested every single link in the list and none are lost.

### (The piece of code that is being used)

```
<script>

var collection=[];
var loadedIndex=0;


function init(audios) {
  for(var i=0;i<audios.length;i++) {
    var audio = new Audio(audios[i]);
    collection.push(audio);
    buffer(audio);
  }
}

function buffer(audio) {
  if(audio.readyState==4)return loaded();
  setTimeout(function(){buffer(audio)},100);
}

function loaded() {
  loadedIndex++;
  if(collection.length==loadedIndex)playLooped();
}

function playLooped() {
var audio=Math.floor(Math.random() * (collection.length));
  audio=collection[audio];
  audio.play();
  setTimeout(playLooped,audio.duration*1000);
}



init([
  'https://ia601509.us.archive.org/29/items/theme-1_202209/Theme1.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/pilotwings-64-n64/shmuvxyn/03%20Game%20Menu.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/1080-snowboarding-original-soundtrack/kyuermtcti/13%20review%20%28Replay%20Time%29.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/1080-snowboarding-original-soundtrack/xzooycupop/16%20white%20out%20%28Last%20Name%20Entry%29.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/pilotwings-64-n64/wcldvwrd/09%20Rocket%20Belt.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/super-smash-bros.-64/mdqmottw/02%20-%20How%20to%20Play.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/super-smash-bros.-64/mbbfevmu/04%20-%20Main%20Menu.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/banjo-kazooie-complete/cmibeqpaly/020.%20Mumbo%27s%20Mountain%20-%20Aquatics.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/donkey-kong-country/hhvtfdcu/02%20-%20Simian%20Segue.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/earthbound-snes/lshsbyfpgm/30%20Onett%20Theme.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/3d-minigolf-deluxe/wgbpcldrlj/Theme1.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/chicken-invaders-pentalogy-the-complete-soundtrack/sggrynne/02-01.%20Main%20Theme.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/commander-keen-4/owjkodrw/004%20-%20Robert%20Prince%20-%20Too%20Hot.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/commander-keen-5/dphrvepv/004%20-%20Robert%20Prince%20-%20The%20Omegamatic.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/commander-keen-5/vmliftfu/009%20-%20Robert%20Prince%20-%20Security%20Center.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/commander-keen-5/qbtuakmh/008%20-%20Robert%20Prince%20-%20High%20Score%20Table.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/commander-keen-5/ahxngboh/006%20-%20Robert%20Prince%20-%20Game%20Over.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/old-school-runescape/gaccwkehoq/Harmony.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/forsaken/xsnwaknf/06%20-%20pure%20bitch%20power.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/hypnospace-outlaw-ost-vol.-2/vsxlvpwlze/06%20-%20Tuba%20Buffet%27s%20Brass%20Shade.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/3d-minigolf-deluxe/ovanelsobo/Theme.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/hypnospace-outlaw-ost-vol.-2/kxnwqerdwn/14%20-%20Cave%20Drip.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/unreal-tournament-original-soundtrack/rytublyiyw/02.%20Unreal%20Tournament%20Menu.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-the-complete-soundtrack/ohklmzln/02%20-%20Opening%20Theme.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-the-complete-soundtrack/orsxlxvb/16%20-%20Pizzeria%20%28Beach%20Blvd.%29.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-remastered-cassetes/mdrtvaguth/LEGO%20Island%20Theme-01.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-the-complete-soundtrack/snhsyvxs/03%20-%20The%20Information%20Center.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-remastered-cassetes/skdekgugcq/Information%20Center.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-the-complete-soundtrack/enszvoam/04%20-%20Elevator.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-the-complete-soundtrack/gyzziywx/09%20-%20The%20Medical%20Center.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-the-complete-soundtrack/elsedwlu/32%20-%20Police%20Station.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/ncedmvrowy/XP%20Tour%20Music.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/bkbmzikopv/title.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/xmrmylwpfs/Windows%20XP%20Critical%20Stop.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/pludoospat/Windows%20XP%20Default.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/wxlfkiicfz/Windows%20XP%20Ding.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/eriixoucwi/Windows%20XP%20Error.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/uqfxdlhpiz/Windows%20XP%20Exclamation.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/cicfoxlvih/Windows%20XP%20Shutdown.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/gpdwfdkrxx/Windows%20XP%20Startup.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/windows-xp-windows-gamerip-2001/evvwkdwoqs/Windows%20XP%20Recycle.mp3',
  'https://ia804608.us.archive.org/27/items/776e6c6f6164732f496d61676/Kalimba.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/club-penguin-gamerip-2005-pc-mobile/egxkhnbyvu/Pizzatron%203000.mp3',
  'https://ia803200.us.archive.org/11/items/club-penguin-music/12%20-%20Jazzy%20Pizza%20Ambience.mp3',
  'https://ia803200.us.archive.org/11/items/club-penguin-music/20%20-%20Charlies%20Here%20Ambience.mp3',
  'https://ia903200.us.archive.org/11/items/club-penguin-music/20%20-%20Charlies%20Here.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/toontown-rewritten-ost/efgjbrotfp/Main%20Theme%20Live%20-%201.%20Main%20Theme%20%28Phase%201%20-%20Relaxed%29.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/toontown-rewritten-ost/gkhswdozxh/Main%20Theme%20Live%20-%202.%20Main%20Theme%20%28Phase%202%20-%20Active%29.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/toontown-online/osftrqbock/Introduction%202.%20Create-a-Toon.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/toontown-online/imtfjziarb/Neighborhood%2001.%20Toontown%20Central%20-%20Playground.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/toontown-online/bxblzigevc/Neighborhood%2002.%20Toontown%20Central%20-%20Building.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/mario-paint-game-rip/lcjeyuuohe/15%20Creative%20Exercise.mp3',
  'https://ia801002.us.archive.org/31/items/HoverWindowsOST/Track%202.mp3',
  'https://ia801002.us.archive.org/31/items/HoverWindowsOST/Track%201.mp3',
  'https://ia601403.us.archive.org/20/items/passport1_202210/passport1.mp3',
  'https://ia601403.us.archive.org/20/items/passport1_202210/passport2.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/3d-frog-frenzy/aojqlxdjyq/01%20MainMenu.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/3d-frog-frenzy/lmviuuhrfq/03%20City.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/hudson-selection-vol.-2-star-soldier-psp/zjdaxhtj/01%20-%20BGM%2001.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/unreal-windows-1998/wktwjboxsq/1-01%20Flight%20Castle.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/descent-1-remake-d1x-rebirth-sc-55-version-gamerip/rygqatae/descent.mp3',
  'https://ia801405.us.archive.org/6/items/total-distortion-bgm-bedroom/Total%20Distortion%20-%20BGM%20%28Approach%20the%20Pod%29.mp3',
  'https://ia601405.us.archive.org/6/items/total-distortion-bgm-bedroom/Total%20Distortion%20-%20BGM%20%28Bedroom%29.mp3',
  'https://ia801405.us.archive.org/6/items/total-distortion-bgm-bedroom/Total%20Distortion%20-%20BGM%20%28Media%20Room%29.mp3',
  'https://ia801405.us.archive.org/6/items/total-distortion-bgm-bedroom/Total%20Distortion%20-%20BGM%20%28Settings%29.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/super-mario-rpg-1996-snes/jojhnpopmv/1-19%20-%20Fight%20Against%20an%20Armed%20Boss.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/duke-nukem-3d/cqddfvjn/01%20grabbag%20~%20theme%20from%20duke%20nukem%203d.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/007-goldeneye-64/piaypemc/1-03%20Mission%20Briefing.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/deus-ex-original-game-audio/txloomvd/085%20unatco%20%28part%201%29.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/deus-ex-original-game-audio/vypjdfaj/086%20unatco%20%28part%202%29.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/deus-ex-original-game-audio/jymdbqtk/002%20title%20-%20deus%20ex.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/super-hockey-94-snes/ygjvodrkil/02%20Menu.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/super-hockey-94-snes/fkdbtzksdx/03%20Game%20Match%201.mp3',
  'https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/perfect-dark-64/lcwnkvyrso/2-07%20Pause%20Menu.mp3'

]);

</script>
```

Comment: hi, it would be helpful to have a reproducible example. could you include the links that make it stop working?

Comment: Are we talking about audio files you are hosting yourself on your own server here - or are you just inputting absolute URL to files on remote servers, that are not even under your control to begin with?

Comment: the question is still unclear. You say it starts working again when you remove some of those urls.. well did you try harder to understand what's wrong with those urls? in which way it doesn't work when it doesn't? you just don't hear the music or you have clear errors showing up in console? the code you shared is hard to deal with also because relies on not listed variables in the outer scope. But since the problem depends on some urls that after removed from list solve the problem.. well there's not enough info shared here

Comment: i agree with diego d. please make the code snippet above reproducible. so, that when we run it, it causes the same bug you experience

Comment: Alright then ill post the entire piece of code ( I can also just give you the website link itself )

Comment: Alright ive added the entire script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 4 links that are not working.

- https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-remastered-cassetes/mdrtvaguth/LEGO%20Island%20Theme-01.mp3
- https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/lego-island-remastered-cassetes/skdekgugcq/Information%20Center.mp3
- https://vgmsite.com/soundtracks/donkey-kong-country/hhvtfdcu/02%20-%20Simian%20Segue.mp3
- https://ia804608.us.archive.org/27/items/776e6c6f6164732f496d61676/Kalimba.mp3

the script never starts playing, because it wants all links/audios to work in this line:

`if(collection.length==loadedIndex)playLooped();`

the buffer function checks wether each audio file has been loaded into the browsers buffer, waits 100ms and then tries again until the audio reaches [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) `4`. there's no logic determining when a song cannot be loaded. so it keeps trying forever and the above condition is never satisfied.

i modified your snippet on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jchfy7?file=index.js). you can try it out there and play around with it.

my modified version is not bulletproof. it's just to show you what's wrong. it tries 300 times to buffer a song. if it cannot, it removes the song from the `collection` array and tells the `loading` function to not increment the index.

this means

- that the `buffer` function waits 300*100ms for each song it cannot load, e.g., the script will start playing after 30s if there's at least one song which is slow to buffer/not found
- the `maxRetries` depends on the user's internet connection, it doesn't know if it takes a long time to buffer a song until it's ready to play or if the song's url does not exist

```js
var collection = [];
var loadedIndex = 0;
var retries = {};
var maxRetries = 300;

function init(audios) {
  for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
    var audio = new Audio(audios[i]);
    collection.push(audio);
    retries[audio.src] = 0;
    buffer(audio);
  }
}

function buffer(audio) {
  retries[audio.src]++;
  if (retries[audio.src] > maxRetries) {
    var idxInvalidAudio = collection.findIndex((el) => el === audio);
    console.error(`${collection[idxInvalidAudio].src} cannot be loaded`);
    collection.splice(idxInvalidAudio, 1);
    return loaded(false);
  }
  if (audio.readyState == 4) {
    return loaded(true);
  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    buffer(audio);
  }, 100);
}

function loaded(incrementFlag) {
  if (incrementFlag) {
    loadedIndex++;
  }

  if (collection.length == loadedIndex) {
    playLooped();
  }
}

function playLooped() {
  var audio = Math.floor(Math.random() * collection.length);
  audio = collection[audio];
  audio.play();
  setTimeout(playLooped, audio.duration * 1000);
}

init([
 // urls...
])
```

BTW: i really like your curated list of tunes ;)

Comment: That did the trick! My commendations, kind sir! Thank you for explaining it too, i've been going on an off about this issue for almost a month now. "BTW: i really like your curated list of tunes ;)" That is good to hear. My website is at https://antiquechair.neocities.org/ (Just follow the instructions for adjusting the view and enjoy!)

Comment: @darkbee, you're right. i modified the snippet. i track the retry count in a global variable now, instead of recursively than before.